# How to efficiently style component in React with a better way in teamwork

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

All:

I am pretty new to React. When a developer hands me a component to style, I always **HAVE TO** ask him to give me another html structure diagram of that component so that I can know what is going on inside it.

But when the component gets complicated(like multi level component nested, I may have to contact several diff developers to **figure out the structure, expand the component and put them together** to figure out the whole structure), I wonder if there is a better way to make this process a little easier(or if there is a standard guideline/spec for me to ask developers to fill out once they finish a component, so that I can get a quick picture which helps me to plan the style, esp the layout.)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the ability to see the component rendering to a page? I usually just use Chrome + react devtools to test and view styling.

Comment: Yes, I can.  That part already done by **HAVE TO ask him**, but there is no style specified, just plain HTML structure.  So I guess your point is: there is no better way to do this, I have to expand those component one by one(even nested level of components) and put them together to figure out, is it correct?